# Allocating a memberless type at runtime v.s. binding at compile time

Tags: performance, f#

Here's two F# scenarios. I have an abstract class:

```
type IAbstractObj =
    abstract DoSomething : bool -> bool
```

## Scenario 1:

I implement the interface into a type:

```
type ConcreteObj = 
    interface IAbstractObj with
        member this.DoSomething bool = true
```

This is then used in the application by instantiation:

```
let foo = new ConcreteObj();
```

## Scenario 2:

I bind an instance of the type with a let binding and use it as a 'free function holder':

```
let ConcreteObj = {
    new IAbstractObj with
        member this.DoSomething bool = true
}
```

And use it as such:

```
let foo = ConcreteObj
```

What are the differences between these usages? In either case, the types don't need to hold any additional runtime state.

- Would there be a performance difference (miniscule)? With modules containing 'let' bindings, is memory only allocated to the bindings that are actually evaluated in other parts of the application?
- Would scenario 1 allocate a small amount of memory to hold a pointer to the instance (even though it is stateless)?

It's fairly important for my application. I use many interfaces for validators and serializers that dont hold any instance state. With my C# background, I'm used to just *having* to create an instance of a class that inherits an interface even if it has a paramaterless constructor and is clearly only a holder of essentially static functions.

Comment: Are you consuming this from F#?  If so, then don't use classes at all.  An F# class containing only static members is very odd unless being consumed by non-F# code.

Comment: Yeah, my codebase is 90 % F#. However, my primary experience is C#. Is using interfaces in general considered to be idiomatic F#? How would you group up specific implementations in the manner I have? I use types such as `type Serializer<'a,'b> { Serialize : 'a->Option<'b>; DeSerialize : 'b->Option<'a> }` which are curried into IO functions etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a more idiomatic option than either of those.  Instead of creating a new type for each option, simply create a record type which has two members which are functions.  You nearly defined it yourself in the comments:

```
type serializer<'a, 'b> = 
    { Serialize : 'a -> 'a Option
      Deserialize: 'b -> 'b Option}

let concrete = { Serialize = (fun (x)->Some(x)); Deserialize = (fun (x)->Some(x)) }
```

So whatever is consuming this should take a `serializer`.

Comment: This is very helpful. Would you consider this practise 'normal' or is idiomatic F# kind of centered around grouping functions with modules versus records?

Comment: I don't have extensive F# experience, however, I did steal the general concept from "Real-World Functional Programming" by Tomas Petricek, so I assume it's fairly idiomatic.

Comment: From a conceptual POV, functions as data is more idiomatic than classes organizing functions.

Comment: Agreed. I guess it is *less* wrong but is it considered the *best* way to approach these issues. I've recoded it as records now but I'd like to get good practises rolling in F# earlier rather than later.

Comment: I beg to differ. Quote the [F# Component Guidelines (page 8-9)](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/fsharp-component-design-guidelines.pdf): "In F# there are a number of ways to represent a dictionary of operations, such as using tuples of 
functions or records of functions. In general, we recommend you use interface types for this 
purpose".

Answer (score 3):

The principal difference between the two is that an object expression has the static type of the interface or abstract class it implements. Whereas, class-based interface implementation is explicit and requires casting to access interface members.

For trivial interface implementations, an object expression is generally a better choice than a class.

(FWIW, I think your performance concerns are inconsequential.)